# Recover zero-byte size file on attached USB storage

Tags: pi-3b+, filesystem, storage

I have an attached USB hard disk drive on my Raspberry Pi with an NTFS file system used as a network-attached storage.

My problem is after a while, some big files, like 2GB and up (usually ISO, Zip, Rar) became zero bytes (some)

How do I (*try*) to recover it? What command can work?

Comment: I'm sure you've heard this already, but problems with NTFS are common and it is a risky proposition using it.  Consider: It's proprietary, and Microsoft does not support it on the Pi (unless of course you install Windows on it, I presume).  If that spec changes for some unknown reason (bug fix, etc) in some way that the proprietary version has some secret means of dealing with, the consequences for running an unsupported version may be anything.  They've actually been [known to do this on purpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_documents#Documents_I_and_II) in the past...

Answer (score 1):

I full agree to the comment that *@goldilocks* has given. But you can try to repair the NTFS filesystem. You find some tools with:

```
rpi ~$ apropos ntfs
```

At a first glance I would have a look at

```
ntfsfix (8)          - fix common errors and force Windows to check NTFS
ntfsinfo (8)         - dump a file's attributes
ntfsprogs (8)        - tools for doing neat things with NTFS
ntfsrecover (8)      - Recover updates committed by Windows on an NTFS volume
ntfsundelete (8)     - recover a deleted file from an NTFS volume
```

If possible you should not use this tools on the USB drive directly. Instead clone an image of the complete drive with for example using `dd` and then work on the raw image.